# Do algebraic tori have no $H^1$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-cohomology, toric-varieties, galois-cohomology

If $G$ is an algebraic group over a field $K$, we can consider the Galois (or flat) cohomology $H^1(K, G)$. If $G = \mathbb{G}_a$ or $\mathbb{G}_m$, it is well known that $H^1(K, G) = 0$ (the latter is the famous Hilbert Theorem 90). What about more general algebraic tori? For example, if $L/K$ is a finite separable extension (we can start with quadratic extensions), and
$$
  G = \operatorname{Res}_{L/K} \mathbb{G}_m
$$
or
$$
  G = \ker\left(\operatorname{Nm} : \operatorname{Res}_{L/K} \mathbb{G}_m \to \mathbb{G}_m \right),
$$
does it follow that $H^1(K,G) = 0$?

Comment: no, for example if you take $L/K = \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ and $T: x^2 + y^2 =1$ to be the non-split torus (so with real points the group $S^1$). Then $H^1(\mathbb{R},T) = \mathbb{Z}/2$, with the non-trivial class given by the non-trivial torsor $x^2 + y^2 = -1$.

Comment: Another interesting example of a non-trivial Galois cohomology of a torus is given in [this handout by Brian Conrad](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/249CS13Page/handouts/H1tori.pdf).

Comment: However, tori as described in your first point (Weil restrictions of the multiplicative group or products thereof), known as “quasi-trivial” tori *do* have trivial $H^1$, because their character module is a permutation module (and in general, cohomology of tori is best computed through their character module with Galois action). See for example §2 (“preliminaries on tori”) of [“Tori and Essential Dimension”](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~mathieu.florence/tori.pdf) by Giordano Favi and Mathieu Florence for more details.

Comment: Just to add one more comment: Steinberg's proof of Serre's "Conjecture I" (the cohomology $H^1$ vanishes for all connected algebraic groups $G$ over a field of cohomological dimension $1$) uses Steinberg's result $H^1$ of every group $G$ is induced from $H^1$ of some torus (not split, not quasi-trivial) inside $G$.  So that explains why we cannot have vanishing of $H^1$ of all tori; it would also imply vanishing of $H^1$ of all $G$, e.g., vanishing of $H^1$ of $\textbf{PGL}_n$ so that also the Brauer group vanishes.

Comment: Great! If any of you want to write up your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: We have $$H^n({\Bbb R},T)\cong H^{n-2}(\Gamma, X_*(T))\cong H^{n}(\Gamma, X_*(T))$$ for any $\Bbb R$-torus  $T$ and any $n\in\Bbb Z$. Here $X_*(T)$ is the cocharacter group of $T$, and $\Gamma={\rm Gal}({\Bbb C}/{\Bbb R})$. This follows from the Tate-Nakayama theorem. For details, see Theorem 3.6 in  [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.13062).